# Paypal Payment Gateway without shopping cart

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I need guidelines to integrate paypal payment gatway. Here is my requirement

1. User would click on pay button on my website to open paypal payment gateway page.
2. User may not have a paypal account. He/she need to enter details of credit card only. (It should not force user to login)
3. User will enter what amount he want to pay?
4. I do not need any response or confirmation from gateway. I would see details of transaction in my email.

Comment: Have you tried searching this site? Have you tried searching the PayPal site? Have you even picked a language to write in?

Comment: Exactly "how not to implement a payment gateway" (?) ;-)

Comment: there are options but that is not what i m looking for. I don't have a shopping cart. i do not have a specific product and not have a fixed amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.User would click on pay button on my website to open paypal payment gateway
>   page.

Create payment buttons using our button creation tool. [Learn how](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_landing)

> 2.User may not have a paypal account. He/she need to enter details of credit
>   card only. (It should not force user
>   to login)

AFAIK **this is not possible**. User should have paypal account and one of the main advantage of using paypal is that users **need not** reveal the credit card details.

> 3.User will enter what amount he want to pay?

[Similar to Donations button from paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons)

> 4.I do not need any response or confirmation from gateway. I would see
>   details of transaction in my email

What email??? If you dont need the result then how will you know that the payment was successful or not???

What you are trying to do above is not possible. If You are using other paid payment gateway providers then you will be able to solve issue 2. Other than I dont think what you ask is possible.

Comment: For every transaction paypal send an email. i will use it for payment tracking.